# How to increase variable value by 1?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm running some If and For cycles. The starting variable **a** value **= 3** and **i = 3**, when code exits an IF for the first time, **a** is equal to 5.
When **i = 4** and macro runs IF again **a** takes initial value **a =3**. I would like to make it continue increasing by 1 after last **a** value.

For example, if after first For **i = 3**, If stopped at **a=5** , on the next For, when **i = 4**, i'd like to have a start value **a = 6 ( a= 5 +1)**.

Then for example when **i = 5**, if the previous IF stopped on **a = 15**, i'd like to have a starting value a = 16. Can anyone help with it please?

```
 ...

    For i = 3 To 10
    ...

    If Sheets("Migrazioni").Cells(i, 5) < 125 Then
    a = 3
        For b = Sheets("Migrazioni").Range("N" & i).Value To y
           With Sheets("Report KIT")
           If (.Cells(b, 4).Value2 = "ATTIVO") And (.Cells(b, 6).Value2 >= 130) Then
        .Cells(b, 7).Copy
              Sheets("KIT").Cells(a, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Sheets("Migrazioni").Cells(i, 4).Copy
              Sheets("KIT").Cells(a, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
             a = a + 1
           End If
          'b = b + 1
          End With
       Next b

    End If

    ...

    Next i

    End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you just set a=3 outside the first For.. Next  loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move a = 3 to above For i = 3 To 10 like the code below

```
...

a = 3
For i = 3 To 10
...

If Sheets("Migrazioni").Cells(i, 5) < 125 Then
    For b = Sheets("Migrazioni").Range("N" & i).Value To y
       With Sheets("Report KIT")
       If (.Cells(b, 4).Value2 = "ATTIVO") And (.Cells(b, 6).Value2 >= 130) Then
    .Cells(b, 7).Copy
          Sheets("KIT").Cells(a, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Sheets("Migrazioni").Cells(i, 4).Copy
          Sheets("KIT").Cells(a, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
         a = a + 1
       End If
      'b = b + 1
      End With
   Next b

End If

...

Next i

End Sub
```